# Find all positive integers $n$ such that $\phi(\phi(n))=3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

> Find all positive integers $n$ such that $\phi(\phi(n))=3$. Here $\phi(x)$ is Euler's phi-function.

I started by letting $\phi(n)=m$ so essentially the first thing I need to do is find the integers $m$ such that $\phi(m)=3$. However, I know that other than $\phi(x)=1$, there are not other possibilities for $\phi(x)=k$ such that $k$ is odd. Is there something I'm overlooking here such that I would be able to actually find $n$ values that work?

Comment: I guess $\phi$ is the Euler totient function?

Comment: @SimonMarynissen Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. If $\phi(x)$ cannot equal $3$, then $\phi(\phi(x))$ can't either, because the image of   $\phi(\phi(x))$ is a subset of the image of  $\phi(x)$